# symfony bootstrap-datepicker - default date persisted

Tags: javascript, symfony, datepicker

I have a problem with this datepicker :http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/index.html

I work with symfony framework, on last version.

I do all css/js file inclusion, i add a class on my field for js, and i use this configuration :

```
$('.datepick').datepicker({
        language: "fr",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true
    });
```

So in regular step, i can select a date with my datepicker.

My problem is :
when i don't select a date in form (optionnal field), the current date is always saved on field.

I just want to remove this behaviour : when no date is selected, no date is persist in entity. I don't have any idea for solve this.

Anyone have an idea ?

--

Thx for you help

my field in formtype is :

```
$builder->add('dateNaissance', 'birthday', array(
            'label' => 'form.tiers.dateNaissance', 'translation_domain' => 'GBPCoreBundle', 'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'input' => 'datetime', 'attr' => array('class' => 'datepick')
        ))
```

My view is :

```
{{ form_row(form.dateNaissance) }}
```

My entity is :

```
/**
 * @var \Date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateNaissance", type="date", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Date(message="La date de naissance {{ value }} doit être un type {{ type }} valide.")
 */
private $dateNaissance;
```

and my consctructor is empty, i didn't set default value

My controller is very basic, i don't act on this field

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: I can just show you the proper functioning of library with fiddle :s i try to make one
otherwise you can see with [demo](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=linked&clearBtn=true&language=fr&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&calendarWeeks=on&autoclose=on#sandbox)

Comment: i update my post with my code

Comment: What happens if you place a option of `'data' => null` within the form building options? If it works, Ill explain _why_ in an answer

Comment: nothing has changed, i added `'data' => null` and when i subit my form, a date has been saved

Comment: This is occurring because the default behavior of [`Datetime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) (you opted to use this because of `'input' => 'datetime'`) is to return the current time. You might have a look at [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) though I feel there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: Ok very thx, i will try to update my code and use data transformers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, verify your entity date field have nullable option like `nullable=true`

Then, If the problem persists, and  you can't find any option to do this trick, you can use Javascript.

On document load, set the datepicker value with an empty string, using jQuery it's like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dateField').val('');
});
```

Now, the default value is empty, and if value change (user choose a date), you save the date, else you save `NULL` or `''`

Comment: thx for your answer, i already use option `nullable=true` and nothing is changed. 
I have tried your javascript trick but nothing has changed.

Comment: I try to remove javascript library and let a classic field for date, and its the same behaviour... when no date has chosen, the current date is persisted. I'll try with data transformer now

Comment: Have you tried to set a default empty value on your entity ? Like $dateField = NULL;

Comment: thx, but nothing has changed :s i try to set default data as null on entity constructor, and form

Comment: I have found my solution (because there is no problem :s) i don't test in view if this date exist so twig print the currend date by default ....... no date is persisted .... Thx for your answers, and sorry for this mistake :x